# Trace attributes in edges of a R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

My graph is

```
nodes = data.frame(GENES = c("GENE_A", "GENE_B", "GENE_C", "GENE_D", "GENE_E","GENE_F", "GENE_G", "GENE_H", "GENE_I", "GENE_J"),TYPES = c("LIGAND", "RECEPTOR", "PROTEIN", "RECEPTOR", "LIGAND", "PROTEIN", "LIGAND","RECEPTOR", "PROTEIN", "LIGAND"))

edges = data.frame(FROM=c("GENE_A","GENE_B","GENE_C","GENE_C","GENE_D","GENE_E","GENE_F","GENE_A","GENE_H","GENE_H","GENE_I","GENE_J","GENE_J"),TO=c("GENE_B","GENE_D","GENE_I","GENE_G","GENE_F","GENE_I","GENE_B","GENE_G","GENE_E","GENE_F","GENE_C","GENE_D","GENE_J"),STATUS=c('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','UNKNOWN','INACTIVE','INACTIVE','UNKNOWN','ACTIVE', 'ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','UNKNOWN',"ACTIVE","ACTIVE"))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE, vertices = nodes)
```

And I want to subgraph and simplify the next nodes `d = data.frame(NODES = "GENE_B", "GENE_D", "GENE_H")` but every time I `simplify` I am losing all the attributes in the edges.

As output, I'd like to get a graph of the nodes in `d` with the direct edges (`order = 1`). I tried with
`subg <- induced.subgraph(graph = g, vids = unlist(neighborhood(graph = g, order = 1, nodes = d, mode = 'out')))` but after simplifying I am losing edge attributes and cannot trace `E(g)$STATUS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some graphs, it is not very clear what to do with the edge attributes in a simplified graph. The `simplify` function offers quite a few options via the `edge.attr.comb` argument. Your graph is not very complicated so several choices *other than the default* will work. For example,

```
subg <- induced.subgraph(graph = g, 
    vids = unlist(neighborhood(graph = g, order = 1, nodes = d, mode = 'out')))
S1 = simplify(subg)
edge_attr(S1)
named list()
```

BUT

```
S2 = simplify(subg, edge.attr.comb ="first")
edge_attr(S2)
$STATUS
[1] "ACTIVE" "ACTIVE"
```